# Efficiency of algorithms

Tags: algorithm

I am a Computer Science student and I'm new to algorithms. We are learning the Design and Analysis of Algorithms course in class.
I would like to know why Time Complexity of Algorithms is measured in terms of 
`O(n)`, `O(log n)` etc. and not measure the actual time in terms of seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: The actual time depends a lot on the implementation. It is not practical to describe it based on time. And you also want to relate it to the size of input also.

Comment: this question should be moved to http://cs.stackexchange.com/, you'll find a lot of useful resources their :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why efficiency is not described in term of actual time in terms of seconds/milliseconds?**

There are many (some of which are obvious) reasons why we wouldn't do that:

- Actual time varies based on the implementation of the algorithm.
- Actual time varies based on the code generated by the compiler (and all the optimization options specified)
- Actual time varies due to time sharing, communication overhead (in distributed algorithm), etc.
- Actual time varies based on the configuration of the system running the program (clock rate, cache size, network topology, etc.)
- We also want to see how the algorithm scales with the size of the problem. A function that describes how fast the algorithm with respect to the size of the problem is more useful.

**Why efficiency is not described as an exact function of size of input and which gives the exact run time?**

- Again, configuration of the system (system architecture, clock rate, instruction set, etc.)
- Again, optimization by the compiler on the code may change some of the coefficients.
- It might not be easy to derive the exact formula for complex algorithm, or algorithm where the exact run time depends on some characteristics of the output.

**Then?**

That's why it is described as belongs to a class of functions.

The advantage of doing so is that we know about the scalability of the algorithm (with respect to the input size) without the need to go too deep into the details of the implementation or the actual system. We can even describes the best/worst possible time complexity of a class of algorithm (e.g. Omega(n log n) for comparison-based sorting algorithm).

The disadvantage of doing so is that the constant is hidden, and only the most powerful term remains. 2 algorithm may have the same time complexity, but one may be faster than the other since it has smaller constant (Floyd Cycle Finding Algorithm vs. Brent Cycle Finding Algorithm). Some algorithm with huge hidden constant only becomes useful with very big input size. Therefore, one should not choose an algorithm based on just the time complexity, but also need to take the maximum acceptable input size into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

[Asymptotic computational complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity) is useful for discussing theoretical aspects of algorithms. The main reasons not to discuss actual execution time are:

- The actual execution time varies greatly depending on hardware, input size and optimizations.
- It allows us to discuss and analyze algorithm with high - or even infinite - execution time.
- The class categorization, also known as Big-O notation, gives us a useful description of the algorithm efficiency regardless of its implementation, *given a long-enough input*. For example, `O(log(n))` algorithm is faster than `O(n)` algorithm for long-enough inputs, but the later might be faster for shorter inputs.
- The discussion is language agnostic, and applies to any software architecture.

Practical considerations should always be taken into account, but the Big-O is the basis for every discussion about algorithmic solution. If you can't Big-O analyze your algorithm your code will never scale.

Answer (score 2):

Time for executing single instruction depends upon hardware and since algorithms are human made so it is preferred to return answer in that specific format . Big O defines worst case  N stands for number of times a block code will execute where n usually defines number of elements of an array object.

Answer (score 1):

A key thing to realise is that these complexity classes aren't designed to describe the actual execution time of an algorithm, but instead to describe the **worst case** execution time.

This is important, because an algorithm that is recursive, and has complexity class O(2^N) may execute equivalent to O(1) if, because of a parameter passed, it doesn't actually have to carry out recursion, but with Big-O notation you're not describing a specific execution of the algorithm - again, you're describing the worst case execution of the algorithm.

Execution time millisecond measurements measure a different thing. Big-O notation describes the worst case for an algorithm as mentioned above, but it does it in a way that is not specific to a particular platform it is running on whilst millisecond time measurements could only describe a single particular execution on a single particular machine. On your average desktop system, particularly if you're building on a managed language like C# .NET or Java, there are things that can cause fluctuations each time you run the algorithm such as garbage collection - measuring the time it takes a function to execute one moment may give 3 milliseconds, the next minute it may give 5 milliseconds. On a faster computer, it may only take 0.005 milliseconds - as you can see, such measurements tell us little about the algorithm itself which is why you need something like Big-O - it talks specifically about the algorithm, rather than a particular execution of that algorithm on a particular system at a particular moment in time.